# Como criar um número sequencial que não se repete, por usuário

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Trabalho em um projeto de emissão de nota fiscal, neste projeto existe a entidade `Emissor`.

- O meu banco de dados **Sql-Server** pode possuir vários emissores.
- Cada emissor poderá emitir suas notas fiscais.
- Cada nota fiscal deverá ter um número sequencial e único.
- Essa sequência é zerada por emissor.
- Para cada emissor o número da nota fiscal tem que ser sequencial e único. Porém para o banco de dados esse número pode se repetir.

### Ou seja:

- Emissor A tem notas emitidas de 1 a 100
- Emissor B tem notas emitidas de 1 a 50
- Caso haja um novo emissor, essa sequência de número de nota fiscal se iniciará por 1.

---

Pensei em usar o *Sequence* do **Sql-Server**, porém com o `Sequence` não consigo manter uma sequência separada por emissor.

Utilizo **Entity Framework 6**.

Alguém teria alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Comment: Para cada emissão de notas faça uma pesquisa no banco de dados pelo numero da ultima nota emitida, adicione 1 e insira novamente no banco pelo ID do vendedor? No caso a pesquisa é feita pelo ID do vendedor tb. No caso o campo dos numeros das notas seria um campo ou tabela relacionada com o vendedor.

Comment: @JoãoCarlos obrigado pela dica, eu já tentei isso. O Problema é que se houver mais de um usuário emitindo notas ao mesmo tempo para o mesmo emissor, pode acontecer d0 número duplicar.

Comment: uma função customizada de hash não resolve? você criar uma função que gera um token de 32 caracteres ou mais? ou melhor, você pode criar numeros seriais e dividilos, você segue uma sequencia de 10 digitos que terminam em um hash de 32 caracteres

Comment: se não me engano, tem opção do EF de `ComputedColumn`, deve te atender. Vale lembrar que, para emitir NF, tem também o campo Série. Logo, emitente 1, pode ter nota 1 na serie 1, e nota 1 na série 2.

Comment: @HebertdeLima o número precisa de ser sequencia iniciando com 1, ai a próxima nota seria numero 2, assim por diante. Ou seja não posso fazer um hash.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis valeu pela dica, vou pesquisar. Se você tiver algum exemplo para mim. Coloque como solução por favor. Obrigado!

Comment: Porque não bloqueia a tabela enquanto está a incrementar o valor?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis fiz a pesquisa com ComputedColum, mas ele só consegue computar usando colunas da própria tabela, exemplo teríamos uma coluna computada FullName que seria FirstName+LastName

Comment: Na minha opinião e pela minha experiência acredito que a melhor solução, e comum no mercado, é seguir a sugestão do @JoãoCarlos de consutlar e somar, juntamente com um bloqueio mencionado pelo LazyFox

Comment: @MFedatto com essa solução, se houver duas requisições ao mesmo tempo, será criado uma alguma fila, para que a próxima requisição espera que a primeira desbloqueie a tabela, ou eu devo fazer esse controle na mão?

Comment: Voce pode criar uma sequence para cada emissor se for limitada as opções de emissores

Comment: Vc deve bloquear a tabela desde a hora da consulta ate o momento da inserção (caso contrario pode introduzir inconsistencia no banco), então vc deve estudar o caso para o seu problema, pois se o tempo entre a consulta e a inserção for grande pode dar um gargalo no seu aplicativo e comprometer o desempenho do mesmo. Não posso te dar certeza se essa é a melhor saida porem é uma saida viavel.

Comment: @RodrigoK.B se você criar uma transação no banco com lock na tabela o próprio banco gerencia a fila e fica transparente.

Comment: @RodrigoK.B. Uma solução simples (se é que eu entendi seu problema) é:

Você só irá ler o ID da ultima nota cadastrada no banco, exatamente na hora de fazer o insert. O sistema não precisa ter conhecimento desse ID antes do usuário clicar no botão Cadastras/Emitir/Gerar... Só no momento em que ele clicar no botão, você fará a consulta para verificar a o ID da ultima nota cadastrada. Caso não queira ficar fazendo consultas desnecessárias no banco, você pode salvar esse id em um documento, como se fosse um log. Isso lhe dará desempenho no sistema, ou criar uma tabela de contador.

Answer (score 5):

Segundo **[a documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-values)**:

> O valor padrão de uma coluna é o valor que será inserido se uma nova linha é inserida, mas nenhum valor for especificado para a coluna.

e,

> Você também pode especificar um fragmento SQL que é usado para calcular o valor padrão

Exemplo:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Emissor>()
        .Property(b => b.Numero)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("(select coalesce(max(numero),0)+1 from notas_fiscais where serie = [Serie] and emissor_id = [EmissorId])");

}
```

> Não tenho como testar, e não sei se realmente o comando poderá ser assim, é uma hipótese, mas acredito que já dê um norte para seu problema.

---

> Sobre a possibilidade de duplicar o número, seria muito difícil dessa forma, mas não impossível. Se definir o `IsolationLevel` da transação para `Serializable` o banco consegue tratar isso, e só permitir um segundo `insert` quando o primeiro estiver concluído.

Comment: Rovann, vou fazer o teste e te falo como foi.

Comment: Rovann, eu uso o EF6, essa propriedade `.HasDefaultValueSql` não existe. Lendo vi que é para o EFCore. O EF6 tem outra forma para configurar mas não aceita Sql. Mas em relação ao isolamento resolve a questão da duplicidade. Mas estou preocupado com desempenho. Vou fazer alguns testes e te falo.

Comment: Fiz o teste de buscar o numero por sql, como foi orientado, isolando a transação. Realmente não houve duplicação , porem não foi criado fila, ou seja a segunda requisição foi rejeitada. Pelo menos evito o problema da duplicidade que ocorria antes.

Comment: Qual erro deu na segunda requisição, que foi rejeitada ?

Comment: Ravann, eu acabei desfazendo a atualização, mas basicamente o erro informou que a tabela estava bloqueada por uma transação. E também percebi que o processo todo ficou mais lento usando `IsolationLevel.Serializable`. Acho que vou fazer como Marcelo disse. Criando uma sequeence por emissor. Mas ainda vou pesquisar um pouco para tentar resolver isso na camada de aplicação e não pelo banco de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Para controlar isso do lado do Banco de dados, você pode criar uma trigger do tipo after insert que calcule esse numero.

Para garantir que não tenha numero repetido nessa mesma tabela você pode criar um índice unico (https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-unique-indexes?view=sql-server-2017) entre o Id do emissor e o numero sequencial.

Mas fique atendo a questão de concorrência no acesso!